# Android - http post returns null response

Tags: android

I am new to Android, I try to post to a Web App with parameters.
However, my code did not work. The "response" from the Web App always null.

Following is my code a button is clicked of the Android app:

```
    final int TIMEOUT_MS = 3000;
    EditText editName, editPwd;

    String actionURL, user, pwd, user_field, pwd_field;


    actionURL = "http://www.posttestserver.com/post.php";



    user_field = "loginId";
    pwd_field = "passwd";

    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    user = editName.getText().toString();

    editPwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    pwd = editPwd.getText().toString();


    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(actionURL); 

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(user_field, user));  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(pwd_field, pwd));


    HttpResponse endA = null;
    String endResult = null;

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        endA = response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a third party library to help you with the http request. For example okhttp (http://square.github.io/okhttp/). It allows you to have a much cleaner call api:

```
 RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
    .add("search", "Jurassic Park")
    .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php")
    .post(formBody)
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Answer (score 1):

Http must be done in a second thread.

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //your http post code here
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            //any updates to user interface here
                    }

                });

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(run);
    thread.start();
```

Also, all code involving the response must be done in that thread and updates to the ui must be posted to a handler. Don't forget to request internet permission in the manifest.

Another option is using the IntentService class. This is ideal for heavy background work.

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use AsyncTask to do network related process in it.It will not affect the main thread.
For example
private class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //you can do the declared the function until  the process finished.
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        //you can call the required functions from here to perform.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
    //This method executed only when the assigned task is finished from doInBackground.
    }
}
```

Comment: Things work when I use WebView to load the web content. Is there any way to load web content in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I try to run my code in a thread as follows but the code not even compiled because of the Activity/Intent statements (i want to display the http post response to be shown in a WebView).

```
public void loginClick(View view)
{

    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


    final int TIMEOUT_MS = 30000;
    EditText editName, editPwd;

    String actionURL, user, pwd, user_field, pwd_field;


    actionURL = "http://www.posttestserver.com/post.php";
```

//        user_field = "q";

```
    user_field = "loginId";
    pwd_field = "passwd";

    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    user = editName.getText().toString();

    editPwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    pwd = editPwd.getText().toString();
```

//       user = "test";
 //       pwd = "steve";

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(actionURL); 

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(user_field, user));  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(pwd_field, pwd));


    HttpResponse endA = null;
    String endResult = null;

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        endA = response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    BasicResponseHandler myHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    try {
        endResult = myHandler.handleResponse(endA);
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Intent myWebViewIntent = new Intent(this, MyWebView.class);
    myWebViewIntent.putExtra("htmlString", endResult);
    startActivity(myWebViewIntent);


    }

}).start();
```

}
}

Comment: The constructor Intent(new Runnable(){}, Class<MyWebView>) is undefined at line "Intent myWebViewIntent = new Intent(this, MyWebView.class);"

Comment: Well, the constructor does not exist. Make sure you use one of the available constructors: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: I managed to compile by declare final before Intent myWebViewIntent = new Intent(this, MyWebView.class); before new Thread(....), however, seems javascript is not enabled